# Laravel - Sum values between two dates

Tags: laravel

I need to sum values using Laravel db::table and get the result between two dates, example:

Date: 05/30/2016 Sold: 1
 Date: 05/31/2016 Sold: 2

So result should be Sold: 3

This is a search result given by a filter by date, i have done something like this with no results:

```
DB::table('sales')
 ->where('date',$date_from)
 ->where('date',$date_to)
 ->selectRaw('sum(price)')
 ->selectRaw('id')
 ->groupBy('id')
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should use whereBetween(), Try this one

```
DB::table('sales')
->whereBetween('date', [$date_from, $date_to])
->selectRaw('sum(price)')
->selectRaw('id')
->groupBy('id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<` and `>` to filter results by a date:

```
->where('date', '>', $date_from)
->where('date', '<', $date_to)
```

Or use [`whereBetween()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses):

```
->whereBetween('date', [$date_from, $date_to])
```

Comment: Hello, i have tried this:

$date_from = '2016-09-25 00:00:00.000000';
$date_to = '2016-09-26 00:00:00.000000';

->where('date', '>', $date_from )
->where('date', '<', $date_to )

And with Laravel im getting empty results, but when using common sql sentence on phpmyadmin im getting values.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `whereBetween` function, and I think you are using a wrong group by:

```
DB::table('sales')
        ->whereBetween('date', [$date_from, $date_to])
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->sum('price');
```

And if the date column's type is a `DATETIME, you should use:

```
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(date)"))
```